# BigInteger Modulo '%' Operation & Less Than / More Than Operations

Tags: java, operators, long-integer, biginteger, modulo

Hi I have an algorithm in which I need to apply operations to BigInt's.

I understand that BigInt's can be manipulated using the Maths class such as:

```
import java.math.*;

BigInteger a;
BigInteger b = BigInteger.ZERO;
BigInteger c = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger d = new BigInteger ("3");
BigInteger e = BigInteger.valueOf(5);

a.multiply(b);
a.add(b);
a.substract(b);
a.divide(b);
```

I need to be able to apply greater than for a while condition e.g.

```
while (a > 0) {
```

Which gives me a syntax error saying "bad operand types for binary operator '>', first type: java.math.BigInteger, second type: int.

I also need to be able to apply the modulo (%) operator to a BigInteger.

```
b = a % c;
```

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

If there isn't a solution then I'm just going to have to somehow manipulate my BigInteger into an unique Long using a reduce function (which is far from ideal).

Silverzx.

Comment: [`BigInteger.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo(java.math.BigInteger)) and [`BigInteger.mod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod(java.math.BigInteger)).

Comment: Great I'll have a Google now, can't see how the compareTo would work off the top of my head but .mod makes sense! Many thanks!

Comment: @AlvinWong you should have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To compare `BigInteger`, use [`BigInteger.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo(java.math.BigInteger)).

```
while(a.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0)
    //...
```

And for modulo (`%`), use [`BigInteger.mod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod(java.math.BigInteger)).

```
BigInteger blah = a.mod(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparing BigIntegers you may use `compareTo`, but in the special case when you compare to 0 the `signum` method will also do the job(and may be a bit faster). As for taking the remainder of a given division you may use the method `mod`(better option here) or alternatively use `divideAndRemainder` which returns an array with both the result of the division and the remainder.

Comment: I can't understand how the .compareTo would be used to check if a BigInt is greater than zero.

Would it be like this?

    BigInteger n = "2712598012958912580129859";
    BigInteger zero = BigInteger.ZERO;
    while (n.compareTo(zero) > 0) {

?

Comment: @silverzx exactly. Or alternatively as I suggested: `while (n.signum() > 0)` By the way in the solution you offer you don't need `zero` simply use `BigInteger.ZERO` in the cycle