# How to use operators for BigInteger

Tags: java, operators, biginteger

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int e1 = 20, d = 13;
        BigInteger C = BigDecimal.valueOf(e1).toBigInteger();

        BigInteger po = C.pow(d);
        System.out.println("pow is:" + po);

        int num = 11;
        BigInteger x = po;
        BigInteger n = BigDecimal.valueOf(num).toBigInteger();
        BigInteger p, q, m;

        System.out.println("x: " + x);

        q=(x / n);
        p=(q * n);
        m=(x - p);
        System.out.println("mod is:" + m);
    }
}
```

I've tried looking for some answers related to it but unable to solve. Please can someone tell me what's wrong in this. I changed the datatype to integer but then the power function doesn't works.

this is the error which I get:

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '/'
    q=(x/n);
        ^
  first type:  BigInteger
  second type: BigInteger
Main.java:33: error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
    p=(q*n);
        ^
  first type:  BigInteger
  second type: BigInteger
Main.java:34: error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'
    m=(x-p);
        ^
  first type:  BigInteger
  second type: BigInteger
3 errors

    .
```

Comment: you can not use these operators on these Objects.  If you read the javadocs you will see that this class has methods to perform what you want to do.

Comment: You have to use the arithmetic methods of `BigInteger`, just like you already do with `pow`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161639/biginteger-modulo-operation-less-than-more-than-operations?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

### Explanation

You can not use the operators on `BigInteger`. They are not primitives like `int`, they are classes. Java has no operator overloading.

Take a look at the [class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) and use the corresponding methods:

```
BigInteger first = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger second = BigInteger.TEN;

BigInteger addResult = first.add(second);
BigInteger subResult = first.subtract(second);
BigInteger multResult = first.multiply(second);
BigInteger divResult = first.divide(second);
```

---

### Operator Details

You can look up the detailed definitions for the operators and when you can use them in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/index.html) (JLS).

Here are some links to the relevant sections:

- Multiplication `*` [§15.17.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1)
- Division `/` [§15.17.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)
- String concatenation `+` [§15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)
- Addition and subtraction `+` `-` [§15.18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)

Most of them work with the notion of **Numeric Type** [§4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-NumericType), which consists of **Integral Type** and **FloatingPointType**:

> The integral types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and `char`, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units ([§3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1)).
>
> The floating-point types are `float`, whose values include the 32-bit IEEE 754 floating-point numbers, and `double`, whose values include the 64-bit IEEE 754 floating-point numbers.

Additionally, Java can unbox wrapper classes like `Integer` into `int` and vice versa, if needed. That adds the unboxing conversions [§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) to the set of supported operands.

---

### Notes

Your creation of `BigInteger` is unnecessarily long and complicated:

```
// Yours
BigInteger C = BigDecimal.valueOf(e1).toBigInteger();

// Prefer this instead
BigInteger c = BigInteger.valueOf(e1);
```

And if possible, you should prefer to go from `String` to `BigInteger` and from `BigInteger` to `String`. Since the purpose of `BigInteger` is to use it for numbers that are too big to be represented with the primitives:

```
// String -> BigInteger
String numberText = "10000000000000000000000000000000";
BigInteger number = new BigInteger(numberText);

// BigInteger -> String
BigInteger number = ...
String numberText = number.toString();
```

Also, please stick to Java naming conventions. Variable names should be camelCase, so `c` and not `C`.

Additionally, prefer to have meaningful variable names. A name like `c` or `d` does not help anyone to understand what the variable is supposed to represent.

Answer (score 4):

Arithmetic operations are not working on Objects in Java. However there are already methods to do so like [`BigInteger#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)), [`BigInteger#divide`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#divide(java.math.BigInteger)) etc. in  [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). Instead of doing

```
q=(x/n)
```

you would do

```
q = x.divide(n);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do operands such as "*","/","+" on objects in Java, if you want these operations you need to do it like this

```
q = x.divide(n);
p=q.multiply(n);
m=x.subtract(p);
```